# mySQL Insert Into & Select & Where issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I need to update one field in one table where the ID matches. I just cant get he syntax right! This is what I have below:

```
SELECT id_col from Table1 (INSERT INTO Table1 (`Date`) VALUES (`2013-10-07`) WHERE `id_col`=`7949`);
```

I am sure it is something simple I am missing .

Comment: That's not valid SQL.

You can INSERT INTO a table (but you can't specify a where clause)
You can SELECT from a table (with a where clause)
You can SELECT FROM a table (with a where clause) and insert the rows INTO another table

You can't SELECT from an INSERT statement

Since your SQL makes no sense it's hard to work out what you want to do - try explaining it in words.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  I didn't realise you couldn't do both at once.  The Update syntax makes much more sense! You can tell i'm new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Syntax :**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

**Examle :**

```
UPDATE Table1 
  setDate= '2013-10-01' 
    WHERE id_col = '7949'
```

Comment: is ok we where all new at some point ! kkk If your question was answered mark the correct answer !

Comment: Trying now, I have 50 seconds to go before it allows me.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1 set Date= '2013-10-01' WHERE id_col = '7949'
```